# Async lock not allowed

Tags: c#, async-await, tcpclient

Basically, I want to make multiple asynchronous requests to a tcp Server. I currently have a working client that is only synchronous and blocks the UI on every network call. Since multiple requests might occur at almost the same time, I tried to do this:

```
private object readonly readLock = new object(); 
public async Task UpdateDetailsAsync()
{
    //I want every request to wait their turn before requesting (using the connection) 
    //to prevent a read call from catching any data from another request
    lock (readLock)
    {
        Details details = await connection.GetDetailsAsync();
        detailsListBox.Items = details;
    }
}
```

I am sure this is not a good use of lock but it's the only way I can think of that could make the calls wait for their turn. Is there an object I can use to achieve this kind of behavior? I thought Monitor would be the same so I didn't try (I understand they're multithreading stuff but that's all I'm familiar with...)

Comment: one way to do it would be to put your calls into a queue. lock on adding actions to the queue, not on the operations themselves. have the queue complete in the background.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Looks like the problem that you have is that threads will block while acquiring the lock, so your method is not completely async. To solve this you can use [SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim readLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1); 
public async Task UpdateDetailsAsync()
{
    //I want every request to wait their turn before requesting (using the connection) 
    //to prevent a read call from catching any data from another request
    await readLock.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        Details details = await connection.GetDetailsAsync();
        detailsListBox.Items = details;
    }
    finally
    {
        readLock.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor correction again, I implemented all of that, it works perfectly. the only thing, the iintial count has to be `1`, not `0`. every time we call WaitAsync() and it returns, the count decreases. Thanks!

Comment: Looking back at this solution after a year, I giggle when I see `await SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()`.

Comment: The `await readLock.WaitAsync();` statement should come before the `try` block. If `WaitAsync` threw an exception, you would be calling `Release()` without ever acquiring a lock. This could possibly trigger a `SemaphoreFullException`. If the `SemaphoreSlim` allowed limited multiple concurrent requests, you may also be allowing more than intended.

Comment: Edit your answer, so await of lock will be before Try.

Comment: i did some test, and found this way correctly sync all threads, but it make the run time significantly longer, demo code in [github](https://github.com/LeiYangGH/async-lock-test/blob/master/asynclock/Program.cs)

Answer (score 22):

This problem has been neatly solved by the [NuGet package `Nito.AsyncEx`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) which has over 50,000 downloads as of August 2015.

From ReadMe:

> #AsyncEx A helper library for async/await.#
>
> Supports .NET 4.5/4.0, iOS, Android, Windows Store 8.0, Windows Phone
> Silverlight 8.0/7.5, Windows Phone Applications 8.1, Silverlight
> 5.0/4.0, and all portable libraries thereof.

> [snip]

> #AsyncLock#

> A lot of developers start using this library for AsyncLock, an async-compatible mutual exclusion mechanism. Using AsyncLock is straightforward:

> ```
> private readonly AsyncLock _mutex = new AsyncLock();
> ```

```
public async Task UseLockAsync()
{
  // AsyncLock can be locked asynchronously
  using (await _mutex.LockAsync())
  {
    // It's safe to await while the lock is held
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
  }
}
```

See the [C# source code on GitHub](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) or install the [NuGet package `Nito.AsyncEx`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/).

Comment: is there any way to let the code run in parallel, and also synced? i have a demo that shows after using `AsyncLock`, the total time used is obviously slower, compared to async one. [github](https://github.com/LeiYangGH/async-lock-test/blob/AsyncLockLib/asynclock/Program.cs)