# Manage concurrent file access with PCL storage

Tags: c#, xamarin, concurrency, .net-core

I am using the [PCL Storage library](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage) in a Xamarin (UWP, Android, iOS) project for platform-independent file system access.

In order to prevent two threads accessing the same file at the same time, and thus throwing an exception, I was planning to use the C# `lock` statement.

However, this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) states that it is not possible to use the `await` keyword inside a `lock` statement.

Since PCL Storage is all `async` methods and can hardly be used without `await`, I am looking for either a way to get `lock` and `await` to work together, or an alternative, simple method to handle concurrent file access.

Thank you for any advice. Please bear in mind that I am restricted to .NET Core.

Chris.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084943/async-lock-not-allowed

Comment: Thanks for the answers and sorry for the duplicate. I focused my searches to much on the PCLStorage angle.